# Discarded side effects with argument passed to assert

Tags: c, embedded, armclang

I have a compiler warning I would like to get rid off.

> warning: the argument to '__builtin_assume' has side effects that will be discarded [-Wassume]
>
> C:\Keil_v5\ARM\ARMCLANG\Bin..\include\assert.h(72): note: expanded from macro 'assert'
>
> define assert(e) ((e) ? (void)0 : _CLIBNS _aeabi_assert(e, _FILE__, _LINE__), (__ARM_PROMISE)((e)?1:0))

The idea is to have no warning when compiled with warning set to "pedantic".
The cause is a recently added pointer check function to my embedded code. The idea is to improve the following:

```
void foo(int* const val)
{    assert(val != NULL);

     /*Use val etc.*/
}
```

to something along the lines of:

```
void foo(int* const val)
{    assert(checkPtr(val) == OK);

     /*Use val etc.*/
}
```

This is because automatic variables are not zero intialised. Thus, it is likely that an uninitialised pointer will not be NULL. This is a coding mistake that I would like to detect (not necessarily my own doing), hence the checks. The following is not perfect, but does seem to pick up more pointer errors (not dangling ones unfortunately).

I have the following code in a header file to implement this:

```
#define INTERNAL_RAM_START ((uintptr_t)0x2000000UL)
#define INTERNAL_RAM_END (INTERNAL_RAM_START + (uintptr_t)0x20000UL)
#define INTERNAL_ROM_START ((uintptr_t)0x8000000UL)
#define INTERNAL_ROM_END (INTERNAL_ROM_START + (uintptr_t)0x100000UL)

typedef enum{OK, NOT_OK}Status_t;

static inline Status_t checkPtr(const void* const ptrToCheck)
{
    if(ptr == NULL)
        return NOT_OK;

    const uintptr_t ptr = (uintptr_t)ptrToCheck;

    if((ptr >= INTERNAL_RAM_START) && (ptr < INTERNAL_RAM_END))
        return OK;

    if((ptr >= INTERNAL_ROM_START) && (ptr < INTERNAL_ROM_END))
        return OK;

    return NOT_OK
}
```

I don't have any warnings with ARMCC 5.06 in my code. From what I can see, my checkPtr function does not have any side effects. It does not access any variables other than the pointer that was passed to it.

Comment: Casting to `const uintptr_t` keeps constness of the pointer, but discards constness of the pointee.

Comment: Did you look for -Wno-assume or similar?

Comment: @2501 I don't want to disable the warning. Rather fix the code so that there isn't a warning.

Comment: @Benoit The pointer is never dereferenced, I'm only interested in the pointer value itself. Would using uint8_t pointers work? I.e. `const uint8_t* const ptr = (uint8_t*)pointerToCheck;` work?

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0774d/chr1383741543685.html) suggests that armclang supports the `__attribute__ ((pure))` and `__attribute__ ((const))` function attributes.  These attributes are for functions that don't have any side effect, their return value is based on the input parameters.  A pure function can also read global state, while a const function can only examine its function parameters.

Adding one of these attributes to your `checkPtr` declaration and definition should silence the warning.

Comment: `__attribute__ ((pure))` and `__attribute__ ((const))` both seem to fix the issue.

Comment: @Flip I have extended the answer to also mention the const attribute.  Thanks for pointing that out.